# Booting from USB fails

Tags: unetbootin

I made a bootable flash drive on Unetbootin for a Linux Lite image, but when I restart my computer and set flash drive as the first boot option it just boots into Ubuntu like usual.

Comment: Have you tried the USB on a different computer? Since you made it using UnetBootin it should be bootable, but its possible something went wrong. I would test it on a different computer to help narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: This could be a bug in Unetbootin or the disk image could be corrupted.

Comment: I'd guess that there's a problem with your bootable USB making it not so bootable. Can you boot to it on another machine?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before.
I just made another live usb with a new iso freshly downloaded from the internet
as said in the other answer set the boot sequence to usb-hdd.
Also some usb's are not bootable or broken i have found this out when asking this to a IT technician